# Relationship between two partial isometries

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Suppose $v,w$ are partial isometries in $M$ such that $v^*v=w^*w$ and $vv^*=ww^*$. We know that there exist partial isomeries $c_1,c_2$ such that $v=c_1w$ and $v^*=c_2w^*$.

Whether there exists a relationship between $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: Why do we know that there exist such partial isometries? Knowing this could help answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $p=v^*v=w^*w$ and $q=vv^*=ww^*$. On the range of $q$, you necessarily have
$$
c_1q=c_1ww^*=vw^*=vw^*q. 
$$
So $c_1=vw^*$ on the range of $q$. On the range of $1-q$ it can be defined as any partial isometry and the equality $v=c_1w$ will still hold.

Similarly, on the range of $p$ you have
$$
c_2p=c_2w^*w=v^*w=v^*wp. 
$$
That is, $c_2=v^*w$ on the range of of $p$. If we consider the minimal version of $c_1$ and $c_2$, that is we require $c_1(1-q)=0$ and $c_2(1-p)=0$, then $c_1=vw^*$ and $c_2=v^*w$.

If you want to find a relation between, them, you have
$$
c_2w^*=v^*=w^*c_1^*,
$$
which implies
$$
c_2=w^*c_1w.
$$
We have
$$
c_1^*c_1=wv^*vw^*=wpw^*=q,\qquad c_1c_1^*=vw^*wv^*=vqv^*=q
$$
and similarly
$$
c_2^*c_2=c_2c_2^*=p. 
$$